# Uncaught #<error> on loading fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures

I'm doing something wrong with fixtures.
I have to models where a Contract has many Contractitems and try to load fixtures for them

```
App.Contract = DS.Model.extend({
  contractItems: DS.hasMany('contractItem'),
  //
});

App.ContractItem = DS.Model.extend({
  contract:       DS.belongsTo('contract'),
  //
});

App.Contract.FIXTURES = [{
  id:             1,
  runtime:        12,
  //
  contractItems:  [1, 2]
},{
  id:        2,
  //
}];

App.ContractItem.FIXTURES = [{
  id:             1,
  //
  },{
  id:             2,
  //
  }];
```

I commented out some dull attrubutes, but the full file is up [here](https://github.com/haslinger/mercator_contracting/blob/master/js/app.js). 
When I load the page, i get an Error

```
Uncaught #<error> VM1615:956
ProfileManager.ended VM1615:956
Ember.subscribe.after VM1615:2007
finalizer ember-1.5.1.js:1802
Ember.tryCatchFinally ember-1.5.1.js:1554
Ember.Instrumentation.instrument ember-1.5.1.js:1810
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer ember-1.5.1.js:22472
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.createElement ember-1.5.1.js:23993
Ember.merge.insertElement ember-1.5.1.js:24944
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._insertElement ember-1.5.1.js:23921
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember-1.5.1.js:6125
Backburner.end ember-1.5.1.js:6215
Backburner.run ember-1.5.1.js:6254
executeTimers ember-1.5.1.js:6552
(anonymous function)
```

Removing the line `contractItems:  [1, 2]` resolves this, but obviously the related objects are not loaded then.
I thought, I did something wrong with camelcasing and tried different versions, but no success.

Ember is used in version 1.5.1, Ember-Data in version 1.0.0-beta9.

Any hints are welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're relationships will need to be defined as async since they aren't loaded in the same payload as the record you are loading.

```
App.Contract = DS.Model.extend({
  contractItems: DS.hasMany('contractItem', {async:true}),
  //
});

App.ContractItem = DS.Model.extend({
  contract:       DS.belongsTo('contract', {async:true}),
  //
});
```

Remember when accessing async properties to use then

```
contract.get('contractItems').then(function(items){
  console.log(items.get('length'));
});
```